# How to convert a data of `byte[]` coming from RabbitMQ broker into a record type in Ballerina

Tags: rabbitmq, ballerina, ballerina-swan-lake

I'm using RabbitMQ module in ballerina package along with a server and a client. In the client I'm receiving the content as a `byte[]` which needs to be converted to a `CustomerDetails` record type before processing. How can we do this?

client.bal

```php
import ballerina/io;
import ballerinax/rabbitmq;

type CustomerDetails record {|
    string name;
    string ssn;
    string phone;
    int age;
|};

listener rabbitmq:Listener channelListener = new (rabbitmq:DEFAULT_HOST, rabbitmq:DEFAULT_PORT);

@rabbitmq:ServiceConfig {
    queueName: "MOT_HOTEL"
}
service rabbitmq:Service on channelListener {
    remote function onMessage(rabbitmq:AnydataMessage message) returns error? {
        if message.content is () {
            io:println("Message recived with `null` content");
        }
        io:println(message.content); // byte[]
        ...
    }
}
```

server.bal

```php
import ballerina/http;
import ballerina/io;
import ballerinax/rabbitmq;

const queueName = "MOT_HOTEL";
const exchangeName = "TheExchange";

service /orders on new http:Listener(8080) {
    function init() returns error? {
        check rabbitmqClient->exchangeDeclare(exchangeName, rabbitmq:DIRECT_EXCHANGE);
        check rabbitmqClient->queueDeclare(queueName);
    }

    resource function post .(CustomerDetails payload)
                    returns http:Created|http:InternalServerError|error? {
        check rabbitmqClient->publishMessage({content: payload, routingKey: queueName});
        io:println("Message sent");
        return <http:Created>{};
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `CustomerDetails` record instead of using `rabbitmq:AnydataMessage` as follows,

```php
service rabbitmq:Service on channelListener {
    remote function onMessage(CustomerDetails customerDetails) returns error? {
        io:println(customerDetails.name); // you can handle fields here
    }
}
```

Refer https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/rabbitmq-consumer/ example

Answer (score 1):

If your requirement is to access all the details defined in the `rabbitmq:AnydataMessage` while having the content represented as a record type, you can define a custom record type using [type inclusion](https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/type-inclusion-for-records/), with your `CustomerDetails` record type as its content type as shown below.

```php
public type CustomerDetailsMessage record {|
    *rabbitmq:AnydataMessage;
    CustomerDetails? content;
|};
```

Now, you can use this custom message type in your client code:

```php
import ballerina/io;
import ballerinax/rabbitmq;

public type CustomerDetails record {|
    string name;
    string ssn;
    string phone;
    int age;
|};

public type CustomerDetailsMessage record {|
    *rabbitmq:AnydataMessage;
    CustomerDetails? content;
|};

listener rabbitmq:Listener channelListener = new (rabbitmq:DEFAULT_HOST, rabbitmq:DEFAULT_PORT);

@rabbitmq:ServiceConfig {
    queueName: "MOT_HOTEL"
}
service rabbitmq:Service on channelListener {
    remote function onMessage(CustomerDetailsMessage message) returns error? {
        if message.content is () {
            io:println("Message received with `null` content");
        }
        io:println(message.content); // CustomerDetailsMessage
    }
}
```